# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] while trying to run Cypress in Nuxt3 project

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, cypress, nuxt3, yarn-v2

I am trying to add the latest version of Cypress for E2E testing to my Nuxt 3 project. However, when I am trying to run `npx cypress open`, the following error appears:

```
/myproject/node_modules/listr2/dist/renderer/default.renderer.js:7
const cliWrap = require("wrap-ansi");
                ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /myproject/node_modules/wrap-ansi/index.js from /myproject/node_modules/listr2/dist/renderer/default.renderer.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /myproject/node_modules/listr2/dist/renderer/default.renderer.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Is there a way to bypass this requirement? I had a similar issue while adding Cypress via yard add, but I bypassed it by adding wrap-ansi of a lower version as a separate dependency.

Comment: Do you have any code details that may help us understand the problem?

Comment: Do you want a package.json copied here? There's no extra code that causes this error, it's a clean installation.

Comment: I was thinking that posting just the error wasn't enough detail to debug. If it's a clean installation, how about posting the install steps, then can replicate to see if it's consistent or something related to your environment.